# Overwrote /bin/bash, after replacing still broken

Tags: 10.10, bash, re-installation

I use Ubuntu 10.10. I abused sudo and accidentally overwrote my /bin/bash file via a typo, so I booted to the LiveCD and restored my copy with a "good" one from the Ubuntu 10.10 LiveOS. This did not fix the problem. Explanation: bash no longer works in gnome-terminal.

- no longer shows username@computername in prompt, just shows $ sign
- keyboard shortcuts no longer work- tab, arrow keys, etc. all insert codes now.
- aliases, also a function of bash, do not work.

Any help on this? Where do I start? I'd rather learn how to fix this instead of just reinstalling the OS. Thanks!

I tried to reinstall bash via Terminal with `sudo apt-get -f install bash` but I can't even get it to install with the -f (force) parameter. I get this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.1-2ubuntu4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

P.S. Once I get aliases working again, I'm aliasing "cp" to "cp -i" and "mv" to "mv -i".

Comment: Open your terminal and type `echo $SHELL` what it says??Also could you post the output of `ls -l ~/.bash*`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the tips. I have already fixed it! I'm kinda new here, so I posted this fact as a comment above instead of as a new answer. Sorry!

Here is how I fixed it!:D

- Booted to the 10.10 live cd
- mounted my hard drive's linux partition in `/mnt/disk`
- did a `chroot` to `/mnt/disk`
- From there, I was able to use `apt-get install bash` to successfully install it!

:D Thanks. I will check out the commands that you have posted here. Thanks so much again. I hope this post helps people who carelessly delete/overwrite bash like I did.
-Slink

P.S. "chroot" is a really cool command. ^_^

Comment: I guess what it really turned out to be is that I couldn't find a "bash" executable that was appropriate for my installation of Ubuntu. *shrugs* at least I solved it ^_^

Comment: Please note: I could NOT uninstall or install bash from within the running OS in which I was trying to install it. This is either not possible or disallowed beyond the capabilities of root admin. I had to install it from within another running Ubuntu OS (used live cd, not another installation in this case, but it's the same concept.) It seems bash cannot be un/installed unless you do so from another instance of Ubuntu. Must use chroot as described above.

Comment: The command to use is `apt-get install --reinstall bash`, which re-downloads the archive (if not in the cache) and re-creates all the files installed from the package.

Comment: I tried that. The error posted in the OP occurred.

Comment: UPDATE: gnome-terminal and it's dependents uninstall/reinstall just fine after I got bash working. Now I broke Terminal. LoL, always tinkering, I am...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what I found the easiest was to load the ubuntu live cd
in " try" mode then open a terminal and `gksudo nautilus`
then copy the bin file from the live cd to my bash dir.

Then reboot and then `sudo apt-get install bash` to update to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! Your way is quite simpler than mine, IF it works fine. ;) I learned the hard way to be really careful with that `sudo` command.

Answer (score 0):

- Type `reset` in your terminal and press Enter. It's a way to reset the tty driver.
- If that didn't help you, delete bash and then re-install it.

**Installing BASH:**

- First delete `/bin/bash`
- Install [bash](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bash) from the Software Center

Comment: That did not work, unfortunately. I just kept getting "bash is already installed" and I cannot uninstall it, as stated above.

Comment: Anyway, I DID IT! :D Booted to the live cd, mounted my linux partition in /mnt/disk, and did a "chroot" to /mnt/disk. From there, I was able to use "apt-get install bash" to successfully install it! :D Thanks.

Comment: @Slink Please make your last comment a seperate answer and mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Yeah Slink. I told you this is THE place!

Answer (score 0):

I used Synaptic package manager, set a filter to bash, and set everything that was already installed to re-install. It seems to have solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to a working terminal `chsh` to /bin/sh or /bin/dash by:

```
chsh -s /bin/sh
```

or

```
chsh -s /bin/dash
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install bash
```

If you do have a working terminal invoking an alternate shell such as `dash` by just typing in `dash` may also work